# Is there any way to find all the DLLs called for a web-request?

Tags: 2007, development, podcasting

We have an PKS application running on SharePoint 2007 farm, I wonder if there is way to find the DLLs are referred for a web-request (Page)?

Comment: Do you really need the set of DLLs?
What do you want to do with this information
  - Generate Reports
  - Use for debugging purposes?

Comment: Yes, we are suspecting an issue with the Download tracker DLL and would like to know where and all it got referred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharePoint Log file in 12\Logs contains lots of valuable information for every request made.

If you increase the logging level you might be able to find the information you're really after.